# Is there an easy way to identify where an exception was thrown from the Exception object?

Tags: c#, exception, logging

So, if I recall correctly, I seem to remember seeing that there were some new annotations added to C# in 4.5 that allow you to pinpoint exactly where an exception was thrown (class, method, line) via a logger or something. But prior to that, is there any built-in way to at least identify the class and method from which the exception was thrown from the actual exception object without having to parse the stack trace? I'd like to be able to use exception object to say, output a message to a log that says something like "`Exception was thrown at MyProject.MyClass.MyMethod(int, string). Message: <exception message>`

I realize there are some 3rd party libraries out there that can help with this, but I'd rather keep it simpler if possible while learning a bit more about the FCL. The intent isn't to change what an exception is, but rather to make them more useful in unhandled situations. For instance, an unhandled exception is thrown and caught by a filter. The filter logs the exception and rethrows it. It would be nice if the log that is created can state "It was thrown over here, see the full stack trace for more info." That would make it quicker for us to view the *where* without having to swim through the stack trace which, in some cases (at least for some of our older stuff) can be very misleading, resulting in chasing our tails only to discover that we would have found the problem quickly if we new exactly where to start.

Comment: You have to be sure that your pdb in included in your build, but otherwise you're probably looking at perhaps creating your own exception object that would do the stack trace / source parsing for you and spit out a message to your liking.

Comment: @JohnSaunders, the Stack trace has a lot of noise in it. It obviously useful for deeper troubleshooting, but it's a lot to wade through for some people. I'm trying to output something more readable. Especially with all of this legacy exception handling we have here, stack traces get lost while the message gets passed along. It's stupid, but if I could at least put something useful in to the message, we'd still be able to see *where* the error happened even though the trace was lost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `System.Diagnostics.StackTrace` if you really need to parse out the individual frames from an `Exception` object:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            Thrower();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            var trace = new StackTrace(e);
            Console.WriteLine(trace.GetFrame(0).GetMethod());
        }              
    }

    private static string Thrower()
    {
        throw new Exception("Boom");
    }
}
```

The feature you are referring to is called [Caller Info Attributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh534540.aspx) and doesn't really have anything to do with exceptions, per se. It is general feature designed mostly for troublshooting. The information is inserted into the assembly at compile time when you use it, similar to `__LINE__`,  `__FILE__`, `__FUNCTION__` macros in C++.

Answer (score 1):

For the source of exception you may look on [Exception.Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception.source(v=vs.110).aspx) property, which provides an information   like:

> The name of the application or the object that causes the error.

You don't need to *parse* stack trace, it's just a string with all data, which may become usefull in certain cases. Remember that `exception` ocures in exceptional cases and you need as much information as it can be get.

Comment: `Source` is just going to give you the assembly name by default not the method name/line number.

Comment: @mikez: correct, that's why I added explanation for using in any way stacktrace string